# How to set Elasticsearch document property to null using the Java API Client and Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a `Schedule` document which contains a map of `Todo`s.
It looks something like this:

```json
{
  "_index": "schedule-index",
  "_id": "sched-id",
  "_source": {
    "id": "sched-id",
    "todos": {

      "todo-id-1": {
        "id": "todo-id-1"
        "name": "laundry"
      },
    
      "todo-id-2": {
        "id": "todo-id-2"
        "name": "dishes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Occasionally, I need to set one of the `Todo`s to null, while retaining the key.
e.g.

```json
{
  "_index": "schedule-index",
  "_id": "sched-id",
  "_source": {
    "id": "sched-id",
    "todos": {

      "todo-id-1": null, <-- SET VALUE TO NULL

      "todo-id-2": {
        "id": "todo-id-2"
        "name": "dishes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to achieve this functionality using the RestHighLevelClient, as shown below:

```java
// using HighLevelRestClient
public BulkResponse upsert(List<Schedule> schedules) {
  // 'schedules' has 1 schedule with id=sched-id
  // that has 1 Todo with id=todo-id-1 and value=null

  BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();

  schedules.forEach(schedule-> {
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("schedule-index", schedule.getId())
      .docAsUpsert(true)
      .doc(asJson(schedule), XContentType.JSON);
    bulkRequest.add(updateRequst);
  })

  BulkResponse response = client.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}
```

Which produces the query:

```json
{
  "update": {
    "_index": "schedule-index",
    "_id": "sched-id"
  }
}
{
  "doc_as_upsert": true,
  "doc": {
    "id": "sched-id"
    "todos": {
      "a": null    <----- SET 'a' TO NULL
    }
  }
}
```

However, after converting to the new Java API Client (Spring Data Elasticsearch fragment), the client seems to refuse to put a null value in the generated query.

```java
// using Java API Client
public BulkResponse upsert(List<Schedule> schedules) {
  // 'schedules' has 1 schedule with id=sched-id
  // that has 1 Todo with id=todo-id-1 and value=null
  BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();

  schedules.forEach(schedule-> {
    br.operations(op -> op 
      .update(ur -> ur
        .index("schedule-index")
        .id(todo.getId())
        .action(a -> a
          .docAsUpsert(true)
          .doc(schedule)
        )))
  })

  cleint.bulk(br.build());
}
```

Which produces the query:

```json
{
  "update": {
    "_index": "schedule-index",
    "_id": "sched-id"
  }
}
{
  "doc_as_upsert": true,
  "doc": {
    "id": "sched-id"
    "todos": {      <----- TODO MAP IS EMPTY
    }
  }
}
```

How can I tell the Java API Client to upsert null values for map values?

**Edit**

This seems similar to [ElasticsearchRepository skip null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684366/elasticsearchrepository-skip-null-values), but in that case the root properties were being ignored.

Comment: This is not related to Spring Data Elasticsearch, as you are building your query only with the Elasticsearch client library. But Spring Data Elasticsearch wouldn't write null values in maps contained in a document either.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.

Looks like the Spring Boot autoconfiguration class (`ElasticsearchClientConfigurations.java`) is setting the Elasticsearch object mapper as `new JacksonJsonpMapper()`.

Looking at the constructor, the issue seems clear:

```java
public JacksonJsonpMapper() {
  this((new ObjectMapper())
    .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false)
    .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL));      // <----- CULPRIT
}
```

Fixing this was straightforward, as Spring will use any `JsonpMapper` I provide.

Adding the following bean in a `@Configuration` class fixed the issue:

```java
@Bean
public JacksonJsonMapper jacksonJsonMapper() {
  return new JacksonJsonpMapper(new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(SerilaizationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false)
    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS));
}
```